# Which version of the Teen Titans exist in the DC Animated Universe?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, teen-titans, static-shock

The [DC Animated Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe) includes a crossover episode between *[Static Shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_Shock)* and *[The New Batman Adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Batman_Adventures)* called "Hard as Nails" that includes this dialogue:

> Static: So where's Robin?
>   Batman: With the Titans.
>   Static: The who?
>   Batman: You'll meet them someday.

I assume that Batman is referring to the "Teen Titans". But which version is he referring to? Is it the one featured in [the 2003 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans_(TV_series))? Or is there some other depiction of the Teen Titans that exist in the DC Animated Universe? And who is part of the Teen Titans in this incarnation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The version which never see the light

> Around the 1990s, production of a TV series featuring the Titans was put in development for being part of the DC Animated Universe. Artist Tommy Tejeda made some art concept for the planned series. The series was supposed to connect Batman: The Animated Series with Superman: The Animated Series. Despite this, plans never materialized in favor of the production of Batman Beyond.-  [dcau.wikia.com](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Titans#cite_note-2)

And from [dcanimated.com](https://dcanimated.com//WF/sections/backstage/abandoned/):

> Very few details are available for this abandoned project. The Teen Titans animated series would have been loosely based in the same universe as Superman: The Animated Series and Batman: The Animated Series, with ties to connect the series together. Little production work is available, with the artwork above created by Tommy Tejeda during the mid/late 1990s.
>
> [image]

The characters depicted in the concept art are:

- The Flash
- Aquaman
- Robin
- Speedy
- Wonder Girl
- Aqualad
- Kid Flash

For characters like Robin where multiple characters have had that role (e.g. Dick Grayson, Tim Drake), it's unclear which one was intended to star in the series.